# undefined reference to Class::method()

Tags: g++, ld, undefined-reference

I'm using a framework called [ROOT](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/) in my code, ROOT provides a large amount of libs, between then there is [PROOF](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/proof) which should allow my code run in parallel.

Should be defined in [TProof.h](http://root.cern.ch/root/html/TProof.html#TProof%3aOpen) a static method `Open` that starts the parallel environment. I'm using this method as the following:

```
//usual includes (including ROOT's)
#include 
//lots of code
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])   {
    //Initialization code
    TProof *p = TProof::Open("");
    // more code
    return 0;
}
```

g++ gives me this error:

```
mini2.o: In function `main':
/path/to/file/name.cxx:279: undefined reference to `TProof::Open(char const*, char const*, char const*, int)'
```

ROOT provides a script that prints all the necessary flags to compile and **link** its libs, I'm using those flags, in this case:

```
$ root-config --libs
-L/my/path/root/lib -lCore -lCint -lRIO -lNet -lHist -lGraf -lGraf3d -lGpad -lTree -lRint -lPostscript -lMatrix -lPhysics -lMathCore -lThread -pthread -lm -ldl -rdynamic
```

What I'm doing wrong? How can I solve it?

Comment: The error you're getting is a linker error, not a compiler error. `TProof.h` is found by the compiler (otherwise that step would fail already), but you seem to have forgotten to *link* against the relevant libraries.

Comment: I'm linking with all the necessary libraries, at least ROOT think so.

Comment: Either way, I edited the question, it should be a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing at least `-lProof` in your compiler (linker) options. I don't really know the framework, so I can't tell you whether this is your fault or a problem with the configuration script.

(This is how I found out: Downloaded the binary distribution of ROOT, checked the `lib` folder and found `libProof.so`.)

If this is not enough, include the other `Proof*` libraries you can find in the library directory.